# How can I check the current camera id in android api 8?

Tags: android, camera, android-camera

I am trying let my camera in android switch from back to front. In order to do that I first need to check which direction it is facing. Therefore I did this:

```
CameraInfo cameraInfo = new Camera.CameraInfo();
if (cameraInfo.facing == Camera.CameraInfo.CAMERA_FACING_BACK) {
    ...             
}
```

This code just works with API 9 and higher. What can I do in lower api's?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You won't be able to use front camera in API 8 and below, because multiple camera support has been added in API 9. Check Platform [highlights](http://developer.android.com/about/versions/android-2.3.html) and this [tutorial](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/camera.html#custom-camera).